# Setting sidebars on Jekyll Hyde/Poole/Lanyon

Tags: jekyll, blogs

I've just forked the Lanyon / Hyde / Poole repo to make a blog about my studies and finding.

Before I discuss about my problems, here's what I have done (Any recommendations to these steps are welcome):

1. I have NOT installed Jekyll. This is because I don't need offline posting. I only forked the repo, since all I need is a static site that can work as a blog.
2. I changed the baseurl in `_config.yml`, and created `gh-pages` branch. I checked that my static site is generated.
3. I tried changing the texts in one of the example posts in `/_post/`, and checked that my native language (Korean) works with the Lanyon / Hyde / Poole template.

Here is what I want to do now:

1. On the static site, I tried clicking on the sidebar menus (e.g. `'Home'`,`'About'`,`'Download'`,`'Github Project'`). I found out that `'Home'` and `'Github Project'` leads to the main page of the static site, and the `'About'` and `'Download'` leads to error 404 (i.e. no existing sites). Here, I want to make sidebar menus to be like

   - Main page
   - Topic #1
   - Topic #2
   - Topic #3
   - Link to Github project

etc., each consisting of the relative posts.

2. I want to remove the feature that all the existing posts appearing on the main page as well. Instead, I want to make a page for 'an introduction to this blog'.

I'm a complete beginner in Jekyll, CSS, HTML etc. I know it will be easier if I learn the basics of these, but at the moment I cannot spare much time in learning new things due to my other researches. I only need a simple blog where I can log my learnings and share my ideas with others. If anyone can share a solution with me, I'll greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: If you only need a simple blog where you can log your learnings and share your ideas with others, I would try wordpress.com.

Comment: @JoostS That's a good idea too. Maybe I'm asking for too much, but I wanted to keep everything in Github so I can use my Github as a portfolio.